# How move data to a location after doing a Databricks Merge

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I would like to know how to go about moving the results of a Merge with Databricks to a location such as Azure SQL Database.

The folloiwng is a typical Databricks Merge sample from:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/merge

I would like to know how to send the results of the following Python merge to an Azure SQL Database

```
from delta.tables import *

deltaTablePeople = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, '/tmp/delta/people-10m')
deltaTablePeopleUpdates = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, '/tmp/delta/people-10m-updates')

dfUpdates = deltaTablePeopleUpdates.toDF()

deltaTablePeople.alias('people') \
  .merge(
    dfUpdates.alias('updates'),
    'people.id = updates.id'
  ) \
  .whenMatchedUpdate(set =
    {
      "id": "updates.id",
      "firstName": "updates.firstName",
      "middleName": "updates.middleName",
      "lastName": "updates.lastName",
      "gender": "updates.gender",
      "birthDate": "updates.birthDate",
      "ssn": "updates.ssn",
      "salary": "updates.salary"
    }
  ) \
  .whenNotMatchedInsert(values =
    {
      "id": "updates.id",
      "firstName": "updates.firstName",
      "middleName": "updates.middleName",
      "lastName": "updates.lastName",
      "gender": "updates.gender",
      "birthDate": "updates.birthDate",
      "ssn": "updates.ssn",
      "salary": "updates.salary"
    }
  ) \
  .execute()
```

Comment: So, you want to save the `deltaTablePeople` in your ADLS? What file format are you looking to save the file in (in delta format or any other format)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Firstly you need to create a mount point in Databricks
   Please refer this link for creating mount point https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dbfs/mounts
2. Once you complete merge operation write the dataframe to ADLS
   Follow this link https://docs.delta.io/0.2.0/delta-batch.html

Comment: Hi @Sharma, thanks for reaching out. I have updated the question. I have created a mount point.  I would now like to send the data to Azure SQL Database. Can you provdie guidance on that?

Comment: Please check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/external-data/jdbc

Comment: Once you complete merge operation write the dataframe to Azure SQL please refer above link for that

Comment: Hi @Sharma, thanks again for reaching out. I have checked out the link. I am very familiar with the link you provided. My problem is that I'm unsure of what I would need to include from the merge statement into say, the following ```(employees_table.write
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "<jdbc_url>")
  .option("dbtable", "<new_table_name>")
  .option("user", "<username>")
  .option("password", "<password>")
  .save()
)```

Comment: Once complete the merge all the data will be store in deltaTablePeople. Post that read that table using any code shown below and store that to a **df**

***df=spark.table("table-name") or df=spark.read.format("delta").load("table_path")***

Then use the df here, it should work

```(df.write   .format("jdbc")   .option("url", "<jdbc_url>")   .option("dbtable", "<new_table_name>")   .option("user", "<username>")   .option("password", "<password>")   .save() )```